# DatePicker on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a problem in DatePicker on android
I can't make it smaller than default size

This is the XML code which used:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
       <DatePicker
          android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
          android:layout_width="70dp"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/addevent_location" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to figure out a way to resize it, but have seen implementations where they utilize the DatePicker as a dialog. The date is rendered as TextView with an edit button, which launches the DatePicker dialog. It saves screen real estate when not editing...

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `DatePicker` widget itself cannot be re-sized, back when I started Android I tried various ways of getting it smaller, but without any results.

If your looking to gain screen real estate by making it smaller, I would suggest you use either the [`DatePickerDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) or one of a many available custom pickers that developers have created (many of them are available on the web and most are well built and customizable).

[Here's a link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html) to get you started with the `DatePickerDialog` if you're not familiar with this widget.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot reduce the size of a view beyond their minimum size. Using wrap_content ensures that the DatePicker is just big enough to enclose its contents.

```
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```